# How to re-run the last N tests that were run in a pytest run that was run on random

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest

I have some flaky tests in my pytest suite. They don't always fail, but sometimes they do. I can get a failure when I run the suite on random several times. For example:

```
    poetry run pytest --count=50 --random -x -v
```

So I'm running on random and failing fast. Under the assumption that the problem occurs due to bad test isolation, I want to re-run the last 2 tests that were run in that run, then the last 3, etc., until it fails again, so I can come up with a reliable set of test orderings that gives me a failure.

Is that possible with pytest?

Comment: Try the ```--last-failed``` option to re-run the last failed tests.

Comment: If this is due to a test dependency, you may try [pytest-find-dependencies](https://github.com/mrbean-bremen/pytest-find-dependencies). _Disclaimer_: I wrote it.

Comment: I don't want to run the last failed test. I'm erroring on the first failed test, so I already know that's the last failed test. What I want to run is the last 2 tests, then the last 3 tests, etc.

Comment: I was under the impression that what you actually want is to find the test dependency. Why not use a tool for this? Apart from my own, there is at least also [detect-test-pollution](https://pypi.org/project/detect-test-pollution/).